# Отфильтровать из списка все, кроме целых чисел

Tags: python, функции, циклы, list

Цель задачи: Создать функцию, принимающую список и возвращающую отфильтрованный список только со значениями, которые имеют тип int.

Ввод:

```
def filter_list(l):
    i = 0
    while i != len(l):
        if isinstance(l[i],str):
            l.pop(i)
        i+=1
    return l
print(filter_list(['l',12,5,'4','ds']))
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
[12, 5]
```

Вывод:

```
[12, 5, 'ds']
```

Comment: В целом ответ @Namerek корректен, хотелось бы добавить что изменять длину объекта во время итерации по нему нельзя.

Comment: `[x for x in li if type(x) is int]`

Comment: Старайтесь приучиться не менять список на ходу, а формировать новый. Иначе на этих граблях вы долго ещё будете плясать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [element for element in l if type(element) is int]
```

---

Вывод команды `print(filter_list(['l',12,5,'4','ds']))`:

> ```
> [12, 5]
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

```
[element for element in l if type(element) is int]
```

это так называемый *генератор списка*.

Я добавлю пробелы чтобы его разбить на 3 части:

```
[element       for element in l        if type(element) is int]
```

Нужно читать так:

«Для всякого элемент `element` списка `l` *(средняя часть генератора)*...,
...когда он типа `int` `(последняя часть генератора)`...,
...добавить элемент `element` в генерируемый список *(первая часть генератора)*.»

Answer (score 1):

А если заменить на наоборот:

```
def filter_list(l):
    i =  len(l)-1
    while i >=0:
        if isinstance(l[i],str):
            l.pop(i)
        i -= 1
    return l

print(filter_list(['l',12,5,'4','ds']))
```